# Trouble creating a third list using items from two lists

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

I'm trying to put together a list (let's call this FinalList) using the combined values of two lists: Customers and Products. Suppose we have four Customers and one Product, FinalList should have a final result of four items (one for each customer).

For example:

```
Customer List:
Customer Code     |     Customer Name     |  Customer Branch ID
------------------|-----------------------|------------------------
001               |      Tom              |      T001                 
002               |      Dick             |      T002                 
003               |      Harry            |      T003                 
004               |      Jerry            |      T004                 


Product List:
Product Code      |    Product Name     
------------------|---------------------
  P001            |   Apple
```

Currently I'm trying to do it this way:

```
var finalList = new List<ProductDetailDto>();
var customerList = new List<CustomerGroup>();

/// productsList is also type List<ProductDetailDto>();

for (var j = 0; j<= productsList.Count()-1; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= customerList.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        var singleDetail = new ProductDetailDto();

        // Copy current products to groupDetail
        singleDetail = productsList[j];

        // Assemble rest of the info
        singleDetail.CustCode = customerList[i].Customer.CustomerCode;
        singleDetail.CustName = customerList[i].Customer.CustomerName;
        singleDetail.CustBranchId = customerList[i].Customer.CustomerBranchId;

        finalList.Add(singleDetail);
    }
}

return finalList;
```

After executing this however, finalList only used `Jerry` as customer for all four items. I tried using `foreach` as well with the same results. I'm not really sure what I did wrong here, and I'm embarrassed that this seems basic to some, so I'm hoping for a fresh set of eyes to spot what mistake I made here...

Also, is there any way I can further optimize this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as always. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
// Copy current products to groupDetail
singleDetail = productsList[j];
```

You don't actually copy current product, but you copy a reference to your item from productsList, and on every inner loop iteration you override properties in the same `productsList[j]` element.

You may want to read more on how assignment works on reference types:
https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2454676

You need to create a new object if you want to make a cross product of two lists:

```
var finalList = new List<ProductDetailDto>();
var customerList = new List<CustomerGroup>();

/// productsList is also type List<ProductDetailDto>();

for (var j = 0; j<= productsList.Count()-1; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= customerList.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        var singleDetail = new ProductDetailDto 
        {
            ProductCode = productsList[j].ProductCode,
            ProductName = productsList[j].ProductName
            // and whatever other properties your product have
        };

        // Assemble rest of the info (these can actually go to object initializer too)
        singleDetail.CustCode = customerList[i].Customer.CustomerCode;
        singleDetail.CustName = customerList[i].Customer.CustomerName;
        singleDetail.CustBranchId = customerList[i].Customer.CustomerBranchId;

        finalList.Add(singleDetail);
    }
}

return finalList;
```

As for me, it is confusing that you have properties like `CustCode`, `CustName` and `CustBranchId` in your `ProductDetailDto`. Are these properties just empty for objects in `productsList`? Consider creating another class specially for these needs like `CustomerProductDto`, so that your intention becomes more clear.

You can optimize this using LINQ:

```
var items = from p in productsList
            from c in customerList
            select new ProductDetailDto
            {
                ProductCode = p.ProductCode,
                ProductName = p.ProductName
                CustCode = c.Customer.CustomerCode,
                CustName = c.Customer.CustomerName,
                CustBranchId = c.Customer.CustomerBranchId,
            };
return items.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for the very concise explanation! This solved my problem. I misunderstood `singleDetail = productsList[j];` thinking that it will copy each iteration as is...will definitely read the reference you gave. Thank you!

Comment: To answer your questions re: other properties, their values were supplied in previous functions, which I didn't include in the question for brevity's sake. :)

Answer (score 2):

This line of code:

```
singleDetail = productsList[j];
```

affects a pointer and not values, so in the end you have a list of the same pointer so you have only the last modification repeated `customerList.Count()`

So you must add the values one by one like `customerList`